# Neural Network: Detect multiple digits from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, neural-network

I have a neural network that detects single digits from an image of a 6 digit display (A digital clock with hours, minutes and seconds).

I've trained it on a picture database of 10k images of the clock (tagged with eg- 14:45:02 corresponding to the clock) using most of the techniques mentioned in this youtube video on digit detection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bte8Er0QhDg

It works well on one digit at a time.
However, I have to do image segmentation and contour detection to find my digits every time because depending on how the picture of the image was taken, the digits can be randomly spaced.
I then send the separated images to the NN to detect the numbers.

The problem is, depending on how the picture of the clock was taken, I can get numbers bleeding into each other, ie 8 and 9 merge into a weird number image and my number detection algorithm fails.

Is there a reasonable way to create a neural network (or some other AI) that can detect multiple numbers at a time?

ie use the entire image as an input and the output be my answer?
If I could even do 2 numbers at a time, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a reasonable way to do this with multiple digits per image. You just have to take a look at the number of target classes that would be required to train such a network:

If you take your current approach, you have `10` possible target classes to predict, one per digit. Given you want to predict the digit value of 6 digits at the same time as given in your example, you would have roughly around `10^6` possible classes (if you don't account for illegal states of the clock such as 99:99:99). Given you have only 10k images to train on, it is save to say that this would not work out with your training data.

I can imagine that it could work for 2 digits; if you have a training set of 10k images with a 6-digit number each, you could enhance the size of your training set by segmenting slices with 2 digits each per image, which would greatly increase the size of your training set. But then again you would need to apply segmentation, and the effort is probably not worth it.

On another note, have you tried using OCR instead? This might be a more practical solution to your problem compared to neural networks.